# Only load sound effect for a the button that need that sound

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio

I'm trying to increase the performance of my site. I got about ~87 right now accordingly Google Page Speed Insight. While it's not the worst, it's not great either. One of the issues is loading too much assets and only use *only* 1, or 2 of them

[image]

```
{{-- Audio --}}
<audio id="audio-poop" src="/assets/be/img/baby/sound/poop.wav" autostart="false" ></audio>
<audio id="audio-pee" src="/assets/be/img/baby/sound/pee.wav" autostart="false" ></audio>
<audio id="audio-feed" src="/assets/be/img/baby/sound/feed.wav" autostart="false" ></audio>
<audio id="audio-medicine" src="/assets/be/img/baby/sound/medicine.wav" autostart="false" ></audio>
<audio id="audio-done" src="/assets/be/img/baby/sound/done.wav" autostart="false" ></audio>
<audio id="audio-delete" src="/assets/be/img/baby/sound/delete.wav" autostart="false" ></audio>
<audio id="audio-swipe" src="/assets/be/img/baby/sound/swipe.wav" autostart="false" ></audio>
<audio id="audio-forward" src="/assets/be/img/baby/sound/forward.wav" autostart="false" ></audio>
<audio id="audio-jump" src="/assets/be/img/baby/sound/jump.wav" autostart="false" ></audio>
<audio id="audio-sleep" src="/assets/be/img/baby/sound/sleep.wav" autostart="false" ></audio>
<audio id="audio-solidfood" src="/assets/be/img/baby/sound/solidfood.wav" autostart="false" ></audio>
```

I check my sites networks tab, I see that it loaded all of these. Those are mini sound effect that I called only when user clicked on specific buttons. Is there a way to only load them when user click on a button that need them ?

[image]

Comment: Do you need lossless wavs? Why not use mp3, aac or ogg?

Comment: @ggorlen I don’t know. I just happened to download it and use it like that. It’s working now based on answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use directly in javascript using the `Audio` API:

```js
function playSound() {
    const sound = new Audio(path);
    sound.play();
}
```

In this way, the audio file will only load when the button is clicked.

Comment: This is a cool trick! let me see and try it today. I will keep you posted. 